# Range Hood Outlet Stopped Working. Fuse?

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, receptacle, microwave-oven

Our microwave is installed into a hood above the oven which also has a light and fan. The microwave suddenly turned off. When I test the microwave in another outlet it is fine. When I test a radio in the **outlet built into the hood** it does NOT work. Checked the breakers in the basement and it is ok. Reset it just in case, but no dice.

The fan and light in the hood are still working.

Above the hood in the cupboard is the fan enclosed in a very difficult to open metal box. I had serviced the fan a year ago and noticed a fuse up in there. I assumed it was for the fan.... but, before I go through the nightmare of opening that box again - **is it possible for that fuse in the hood to be for the microwave's plug only?** If so, our problem might be as simple as that fuse, otherwise I'm at a loss.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: It's definitely possible that the fuse could be for the outlet -- was it the only fuse in the box?

Comment: Look for tripped GFCI outlets as well.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yes indeed. It is a round-glass fuse up in the hood. Looks like plug, light and fan all pass through the box with the fuse, but they come out separate areas. Will replace fuse and see how it goes.

Comment: If you get us up-close shots of inside the box, we might be able to tell you what all runs off that fuse...

Comment: Brand and model of the microwave/hood and we may find the schematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out replacing the fuse did the trick.

So, YES, the fuse in the range hood can affect the microwave's plug only without affecting the light and fan.

Kenmore brand hood.